# perl regex substring

Tags: regex, perl

```
$str="!bypass";
```

I need return string that only start with regex "!"
How can I return bypass ?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to remove the exclamation mark from the beginning of a string?

Answer (score 3):

To match strings that start with a `!` you need this pattern. The `^` is the anchor at the beginning of the string.

```
/^!/
```

If you want to capture the stuff after the `!`, you need this pattern. The parenthesis `()` are a *capture group*. They tell Perl to grab everything between them and keep it. The `.` means *any character*, and the `+` is a quantifier for *as many as possible, at least one*. So `.+` means *grab everything*.

```
/^!(.+)/
```

To apply it, do this.

```
$str =~ m/^!(.+)/;
```

And to get the `"bypass"` out of that pattern, use the `$1` match variable that was assigned automatically by Perl with the `m//` operation.

```
print $1; # will print bypass
```

To make that conditional, it would be:

```
print $1 if $str =~ m/^!(.+)/;
```

The `if` here is in [*post-fix notation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), which lets you omit the block and the parenthesis. It's the same as the following, but shorter and easier to read for single statements.

```
if ( $str =~ m/^!(.+)/ ) {
    print $1;
}
```

If you want to permanently change `$str` to not have an exclamation mark at the beginning, you need to use a substitution instead.

```
$str =~ s/^!//;
```

The `s///` is the substitution operator. It changes `$str` in place. The original value including the `!` will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Use `^!\K.+`.

It works this way:

- `^!` - Match initial `!` (but this will soon change, see below).
- `\K` - *Keep* - "forget" about what you have matched so far and set the starting point of the match here (after the `!`).
- `.+` - Match non-empty sequence of chars.

Due to `\K`, only the last part (`.+`) is actually matched.

Comment: How would you use the match with `\K` in an actual program? What would the logic around it be?

Comment: You can program it e.g. as follows:

    my $str="!bypass";
    if ($str =~ /^!\K.+/) {
      print "Match: $&\n";
    } else {
      print "No match\n";
    } Of course, the matched content is **after** \K.

Comment: You should add that to your answer. It's a more advanced technique, and I actually didn't know the `\K`.